# How can a cygwin mount point be deleted

Tags: cygwin

Win 7

cygcheck (cygwin) 3.1.7

I created some mount points (mount winname name) years ago. I've just installed a new HDD and have to change the links.

There are some links where the owner:group is "?:?" (attributes are "??????????", size is "?" and time is "?"). I can not delete these links, change owner:group or chmod. They are inaccessible and return with an error message of "cannot access 'symlink': No such file or directory" whenever an operation is tried on them. But, they are listed under 'ls'.

I can not do a umount name. The error message is:

Is there any way that I can just delete these things and start over?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just forgot about mount tables (fstab). editing /etc/fstab solved my issues.

Sorry to have wasted your time.